# Bitbucket: pull-request-notifier-plugin how to pass target branch name in invoking URL?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

I am using [pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket/blob/master/README_jenkins.md) to automate trigger of jenkins job on creation of pull request in Bitbucket.

I want to pass the target branch name through invoking URL and verify the same in jenkins job.

currently, I am passing it like below but its not working,

```
http://localhost:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters?token=secret&paramName=${PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH}
```

How to pass the target branch name to jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

This can be complicated as there were some changes in Jenkins in version 2.0.

You will need to do the following to allow parameters to be passed from the webrequest to jenkins job.

1. Whitelist the parameters you want to pass, as just adding parameters is no longer allowed by Jenkins.

> “-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitStatus.safeParameters=paramName”

This parameter can be added in the following ways:

```
Windows 
File: JENKINS_HOME/Jenkins.xml
These need to be added before the -jar term as parameters after this are ignored.
Ubuntu:
File: /etc/default/Jenkins
Property: JAVA_ARGS
RedHat:
File: /etc/sysconfig/Jenkins
Property: JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

2. Add the parameter to the job in Jenkins.

You can debug this using the jenkins logging to see if the web request is being triggered.

A more comprehensive write up of the entire process is available [here](https://dengelonsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/jenkins-pull-request-and-pipeline.html)